# special characters in html class element preventing scrapy from capturing element?

Tags: python, scrapy, special-characters

I've used Scrapy to scrape a few websites before so am familiar with the syntax and can't seem to capture the following class element:
[image]

This is what I've most recently tried:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import black

class PeopleperhourSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'peopleperhour'
    start_urls = ['https://www.peopleperhour.com/hire-freelancers/technology-programming']

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        data = {}

        for card in response.xpath("//ul[@class='list⤍ResultsList⤚21s3j']/li/div/div/h2/a").get():
            data['url'] = card.xpath('href').extract()
    
        for card in sel.css('.list⤍ResultsList⤚21s3j > li > div > div > h2 > a::attr(href)').extract():
            yield card
```

Nothing is being returned and when I try to debug in the scrapy shell, I've noticed that the special characters become:
[image]

Everything I've found has dealt in outputting special characters scraped from a site and hasn't addressed special characters found in the class name itself. I'm not sure if the text would need to be encoded a certain way to be read correctly? If anyone has experience capturing elements with special characters, I would appreciate any insight you may be able to share!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example to get link and title:

```py
def parse(self, response):
    for title in response.xpath("//ul[contains(@class, 'ResultsList')]/li//a[@title]"):
        url = title.xpath('./@href').get()
        title = title.css('::text').get()

        yield {
            'url': url,
            'title': title
        }
```

Outout will be following:

```
{
    "url": "https://www.peopleperhour.com/freelancer/technology-programming/adrian-wordpress-speed-optimization-vqwmznw",
    "title": "Adrian M."
},
{
    "url": "https://www.peopleperhour.com/freelancer/technology-programming/hassan-farooq-php-mysql-wordpres-drupal-laravel-wwjnvj",
    "title": "Hassan F."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to scrape [this](https://www.peopleperhour.com/hire-freelancers) website.

If you look more closely, you can notice that `a` has to parent element `h2`.
With that said, you can use CSS selectors to scrape it.
It would look something like this:

```
title = title.css('h2 > a ::text').getAll()
```

This is the most simple solution, but it's not the best because there could be more `h2` on that have child element `a`. So to fix it, you could do something like this:

```
title = title.css('.title-nano > a ::text').getAll()
```

Here we find all elements with class "title-nano", which has a child element.

Keep in mind that .getAll() returns list of elements.